# Postgres Restore in CMD (Java) not responding anymore, while same command is executed well in CMD

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I have written some code for Windows OS task scheduler to automatically get backups and restore it locally to my postgres database.

All the stuf is working till final step, restore command. While this same command executed directly in cmd shell works perfectly.

I think I am not capturing the end of the restore, which is warning....

Does someone has an idea why the cmd script is not exectued and finished? Should i use another method, close the connections?

Here is my code

```
                    // 7 restore database

                    ProcessBuilder processBuilder21 = new ProcessBuilder();
                    // Windows
                    String cmd1 = "pg_restore -h localhost -p " + postgresPort + " -U " + postgresUsername + " -d "
                            + postgresDbname + " " + dbLocation;

                    processBuilder21.command("cmd.exe", "/c", cmd1);
                    System.out.println(cmd1);
                    try {
                        Process process = processBuilder21.start();
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                        String line;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(cmd1);
                        }

                        int exitCode = process.waitFor();
                        System.out.println("Exitcode: "+ exitCode);
                        if (exitCode == 0) {
                            System.out.println("Database restored: " + postgresDbname);
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Error database restore");
                        }
                        System.out.println(cmd1);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not reading the commands error output, so if a lot of error output is generated, the error stream buffer runs full and blocks the command.

Call [`processBuilder21.redirectErrorStream(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream-boolean-) to merged the commands error output into the standard output.

Other changes:

- You can combine the statements.
- You need to close the stream, preferably using try-with-resources.
- You probably want to change the statement inside the `while` loop to print `line`, not `cmd1`.

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", cmd1)
        .redirectErrorStream(true)
        .start();
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
    for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
int exitCode = process.waitFor();
```

Of course, since you're just printing the output, you might as well just let the system do it for you, by calling [`inheritIO()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO--).

```
int exitCode = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", cmd1)
        .inheritIO()
        .start()
        .waitFor();
```

---